# Sending array of integers as a value of volley's params returns 400 code

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to send the following json:

```
{"communities" : [381, 382, 383, 384, 385]}
```

I do not have problemst using this code when I am trying to send a hash map with String as key and value but in this case when the value should be array of integers the server doesn't recognize it as such and returns me code 400:

```
JSONObject dataToPost = new JSONObject();

JSONArray jsa = new JSONArray();
jsa.put(381);
jsa.put(382);
jsa.put(383);
jsa.put(384);
jsa.put(385);
jsa.put(386);

try {
    dataToPost.put("communities", jsa);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

final JSONObject dataFinal = dataToPost;

Log.i("fdsfs", dataFinal.toString());

StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, GlobalValues.registerSetCommunities,

        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                manageSuccessResponse(response);
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                manageErrorResponse(error);
            }
        }
) {

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() {
        try {
            return dataFinal.toString().getBytes("utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + Credentials.getAuthToken(mContext));
        return headers;
    }
};

postRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        GlobalValues.request_timeout,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext).add(postRequest);
```

Another way that I tried was with JsonObjectRequest. Here is the code:

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, GlobalValues.registerSetCommunities, dataFinal, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.i("SENDMOVE", response.toString());
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        manageErrorResponse(error);
    }
}) {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("cache-control", "no-cache");
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + Credentials.getAuthToken(mContext));
        return headers;
    }
};

request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        GlobalValues.request_timeout,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext).add(request);
```

Comment: Try printing the value in your server side if the request was successfully received. We cannot really tell which code is causing that error.

Answer (score 0):

Using the second way and removing

```
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

did the trick.